# GDB 8.1 can not track value of std::string variable in single thread simple program

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, mingw

Created default qt widget project :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     std::string s = QDir::currentPath().toLocal8Bit().constData();
     std::string s2 = QDir::currentPath().toLocal8Bit().constData();
     std::string s3 = "dsdasda";
     int t = s.size();
     char str[1024]= { 0 };
     char str2[1024]= { 0 };
     std::memcpy(str,s.c_str(),s.size ());
     std::memcpy(str2,&s,s.size ());
     int i = 0;
     while(str[i]) std::cout << str[i++] ;

    char * pch;

       pch = strtok (str,"/");
       while (pch != NULL)
       {
         printf ("%s\n",pch);
         pch = strtok (NULL, "/");
       }

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Also my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui network widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Pasted main.cpp only because other file are default and do not refer to my question.

Here is the errors text (or maybe it is warnings) :

```
main.cpp:11:11: error: no type named 'string' in namespace 'std'
main.cpp:17:11: error: no member named 'memcpy' in namespace 'std'
main.cpp:3:10: error: 'cstring' file not found
```

And other the same.

I do not know why there are so many errors (warnings?), why do it compile and launch if there is any error and how to fix all that errors.

Comment: `char str[1024]= { 0 };
     char str2[1024]= { 0 };
     std::memcpy(str,s.c_str(),s.size ());
     std::memcpy(str2,&s,s.size ());` - *Why*? Why would you ever want to do that? And why are you converting all those nice `QString`s to `std::string`s?

Comment: Is it possible your build is optimized? I don't know how to QMake, but you should have something along the lines of `-Og -ggdb` in your build commands and definitely not `-O1`, `-O2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in your .pro file: `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/c++/{gcc_version}/`

Then try to use `#include <iostream>` in your code!

Comment: `#include <iostream>`  already written on the 5th line of my code . My OS - windows 10, i do not know what is that path and how to fit it in my case.

Comment: @Gaurav Goswami It's path of Linux. Just find path of your cpp compiler in windows and write it.